# how to call another activity from the thread in android from the first page

Tags: android

i am making an test engine in android. i want to call "SignUpActivity" from "StartEngineActivity" but it is not working properly . it some times  shows message "Unfortunately stopped working" message. so what is the error in the code?

**I am writing the following code to call SignUpActivity.class from StartEngineActivity.class**

```
public class StartEngineActivity extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    TextView t1;
    ProgressBar pbar;
    int progressStatus=0;
    String status="";

    Handler progressHandler= new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_startengine);
        pbar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(id.progressBar2);
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(id.textView1);

        Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            private boolean flag;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (progressStatus<=100) {
                    if(progressStatus<20){
                        status="Loading Exam Modules...";


                        progressStatus++;
                    }
                    else if(progressStatus<70){
                        status="Starting Test Engine..";

                        progressStatus++;
                    }
                    else if(progressStatus<98){
                        status="Almost Completed...";

                        progressStatus++;
                    }else if(progressStatus<100){
                        status="Load Completed...";

                        progressStatus++;

                    }else if(progressStatus>=100){
                        flag=true;


                    }
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(70);
                    }catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                    progressHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            t1.setText(status);
                            pbar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                            if(flag){
                                Intent n = new Intent(StartEngineActivity.this,SignUpActiviry.class);
                                startActivity(n);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }

            }
        });

        th.start();
    }
```

}

when i run this code it works but it get stuck when progressStatus==100. Please resolve this problem.

**here is the log when i run this code..**

```
07-21 01:40:54.255: W/Trace(915): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:31.143: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:31.163: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:31.453: D/dalvikvm(1003): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 457K, 10% free 5348K/5924K, paused 40ms, total 40ms
07-21 01:42:31.473: I/dalvikvm-heap(1003): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.224MB for 1982056-byte allocation
07-21 01:42:31.604: D/dalvikvm(1003): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 7283K/7860K, paused 135ms, total 135ms
07-21 01:42:31.804: D/dalvikvm(1003): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 6% free 7445K/7860K, paused 78ms+31ms, total 197ms
07-21 01:42:31.954: D/dalvikvm(1003): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 5% free 8064K/8484K, paused 40ms, total 41ms
07-21 01:42:32.164: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.164: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.174: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.174: I/Choreographer(1003): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-21 01:42:32.174: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.174: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.194: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.194: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.194: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.204: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.204: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.204: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.224: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.224: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.224: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.403: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.493: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.653: W/EGL_emulation(1003): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-21 01:42:32.653: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.684: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.704: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:32.753: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.224: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.324: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.324: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.424: I/Choreographer(1003): Skipped 73 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-21 01:42:33.424: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.444: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.464: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.464: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.474: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.474: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.494: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.594: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.594: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.614: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.614: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.734: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:33.958: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:34.023: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:34.023: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:34.023: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:34.033: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:34.043: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
0
07-21 01:42:34.393: W/EGL_emulation(1003): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-21 01:42:34.393: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:34.425: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:34.425: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:34.864: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:34.874: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:35.164: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:35.543: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:35.563: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:35.573: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:35.783: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.354: D/dalvikvm(1003): GC_CONCURRENT freed 93K, 3% free 9772K/9976K, paused 75ms+137ms, total 502ms
07-21 01:42:36.524: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.575: I/Choreographer(1003): Skipped 151 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-21 01:42:36.584: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.614: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.614: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.624: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.624: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.624: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.664: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.754: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.764: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.764: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.774: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.774: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.913: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.933: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.953: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.953: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.953: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.983: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.983: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:36.983: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:37.003: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:37.003: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:37.013: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:37.675: W/EGL_emulation(1003): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-21 01:42:37.675: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:37.694: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:37.704: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:37.704: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:37.804: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:37.864: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:37.965: W/EGL_emulation(1003): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-21 01:42:37.965: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:37.984: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:38.014: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

07-21 01:42:40.243: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:40.313: I/Choreographer(1003):** Skipped 200 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.**
07-21 01:42:40.544: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:40.754: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:40.754: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:40.754: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:40.864: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:40.874: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:40.874: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:40.894: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:40.924: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.005: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.024: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.024: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.044: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.044: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.084: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.084: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.084: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.094: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.104: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.114: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.144: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.144: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.154: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.174: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.174: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.174: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

07-21 01:42:41.934: W/EGL_emulation(1003): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-21 01:42:41.934: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.943: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.953: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:41.953: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:42.094: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:42.194: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:42.294: W/EGL_emulation(1003): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-21 01:42:42.294: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:42.304: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:42.314: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:42.344: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:42.474: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:42.564: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:42.624: W/EGL_emulation(1003): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-21 01:42:42.624: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:42.654: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:42.673: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:42.744: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:43.173: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:43.493: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:43.524: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:43.644: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:44.094: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:44.174: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:44.174: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:44.403: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:45.023: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:45.105: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:45.105: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:45.225: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:45.484: D/dalvikvm(1003): GREF has increased to 201
07-21 01:42:45.524: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:45.555: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:45.565: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:45.804: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:46.423: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:46.513: I/Choreographer(1003): Skipped 325 frames!  The application may be doing **too much work on its main thread.**

07-21 01:42:47.224: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 01 01:42:47.473: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:47.503: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:47.503: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:47.513: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:47.544: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:47.544: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:47.563: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:47.693: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:47.813: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:48.004: W/EGL_emulation(1003): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-21 01:42:48.004: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0


07-21 01:42:56.064: I/Choreographer(1003): Skipped 516 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-21 01:42:56.184: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.184: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.184: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.194: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.194: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.194: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.205: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.373: D/dalvikvm(1003): GC_CONCURRENT freed 511K, 6% free 11217K/11840K, paused 5ms+125ms, total 644ms
07-21 01:42:56.413: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.463: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.463: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.463: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.504: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.564: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.633: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.643: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.643: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.643: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.643: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.643: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.643: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.653: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.653: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.653: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.653: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.663: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.713: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.763: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.763: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.763: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.783: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.845: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.913: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:42:56.913: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:05.154: D/dalvikvm(1003): GREF has increased to 301
07-21 01:43:06.843: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:06.853: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:06.853: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:06.853: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:06.853: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:06.853: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:06.893: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:06.893: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:06.893: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:06.893: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:06.903: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:06.924: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:06.953: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:06.953: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:06.963: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:13.243: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:13.443: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-21 01:43:13.594: D/dalvikvm(1003): GC_CONCURRENT freed 752K, 7% free 12467K/13324K, paused 75ms+166ms, total 1188ms
07-21 01:43:14.204: W/Trace(1003): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: have u added the Activity to the Manifest? plus u can change the Handler to RunOnUiThread(Runnable)

Comment: Try including the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in the intent before `startActivity()`.

Comment: yes i have added the mainfiest to the activity and i have also tried to add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK before the startActivity. but it is not working.. it hanged to my first page when i tries to close the program the program is not closing..

Comment: Can you post the logcat output from when the app force closes. If you select 'error' in eclipse logcat window, it'll show you only error logs.

Comment: hi @Shivam i have already posted logcat. and in the error filter there is nothing shown. so i have posted verbose output. and my application is not forcibly closing... actually it is hanged on the first page and nothing is working.. in that case i have to close emulator and start it again.. plz help.

Answer (score 0):

try it. Handler.sendMessage(msg) in thread, and catch it on Main Thread, because startActivity() can't call from thread.

[android.os.Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessage%28android.os.Message%29)